Разработка под android с qt и kotlin
Сейчас работаю в колл центре, и хочу написать приложение для обзвона номеров, т.е. звонить номера из таблицы excel-ля и проверять на автоответчик и валидный ли номер вообще. Из языков я знаю только c++ и учу qt где-то месяцев 9 наверное, потому выбор у меня не велик ;)
Писать на чистых плюсах я понимаю что невозможно, в любом случае нужен будет kotlin или java.
Но и учить с нуля эти языки я не особо хочу сейчас, потому хочу использовать kotlin + qt/C++, что вроде как вполне реально (qt же поддерживает android, и даже ios вроде как)
Я скачал уже себе android studio, там sdk ndk это все тоже, и смог запустить на своем телефоне типо hello world-а на андроиде с отладкой, но как мне теперь писать на плюсах и qt? И использовать функции kotlin-а? Я читал документацию qt, но там используется qt creator, а я использую vs code. Я ведь могу использовать vs code для андроида? Ну там поставить расширение может какое-то для отладки?
Вопрос в общем то, как мне это все настроить? Сказать cmake наверное или gradle что вот тут у меня код котлина, а тут qt/c++ и ты вот это все компилируй и запускай.
И где мне подсмотреть использование kotlin-а и qt/c++ вместе? Ну например сделаю функцию в файле с котлином для звонка, а из плюсов буду эту функцию вызывать

Хотите писать на qt/c++ для Андроид - пишите. Зачем вам сюда Котлин и его какие-то "функции"? https://www.qt.io/blog/getting-started-with-qt-for-android

а qt позволяет, например, звонить по номеру? Просто ничего такого я не находил, но в котлине есть action_call (знакомый говорил) @EugeneKrivenja

ACTION_CALL это про Intent, который элементарно создается в Qt и отправляется в систему. Вот пример с сервисом: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-services.html#start-a-service-on-demand https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qandroidintent.html
